# Looking for a good Python IDE

Tags: windows, python, ide, programming

I am currently using visual studio code, but you can't run python code that requires input easily from inside the IDE. What is a good alternative to visual studio code to program in python that you can download on Windows? It needs to be able to run Python code inside the IDE (including using user input). I've heard and seen many other IDEs such as pycharm and spider, but I was wondering what you guys recommend. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question and we will reopen it, thanks!

Comment: I can't recommend PyCharm enough

Comment: If your only requirements are for it to run on windows and be able to run python code, you might be better off just sticking with IDLE.